# Access Database Timesheet - Can't get form to store data in 2 tables

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, relationships

I have a database timesheet (I will email it to you if you want to see more about how it is set up).

Everything is set up and working fine EXCEPT: I have a form that employees use to enter the following information (which is stored in a table: TimesheetT): Date, Username, Project Name, Description, Time. The form is a multi-entry form, so they can enter multiple records on the one screen. I want them to also be able to enter a "sign-in" and "sign-out" time at the top and have this information saved in the database.

The problem is that if I just add "sign in" and "sign out" fields to the TimesheetT table, it requires this information to be entered for every single entry (employees might have 15 different entries per day).

I am looking for a way to just enter a sign in and sign out time in the same form that users use to type in their daily timesheet information.

Any ideas? I have tried a few things but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Split your 'timesheet' table and your 'timerows' table. Same as you would normally have an 'invoice header' and 'invoice lines' table. One timesheet 'header' can have one or many child rows. It is in this 'header' that you would put the sign in and sign out fields.